# read.csv/write.csv Synchronization in R

Tags: r, synchronization, read.csv

I have multiple instances of a code running on bunch of projects. The list of projects are included in projList.csv. When an R instance picks up a  project it writes 1 in front of the project name in the projList.csv to prevent the other instances to redo what has already been done.

I want to avoid the following synchronization problems:
- I do not want to allow reading the list file while another process is writing on it.
- I do not want to allow writing when another process is wither writing on it or reading it.

Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but I think they may be a cleaner and easier way to do it with parallelization. To directly address your question though, you could create a lock file (a file with the same name as the projlist, with a '.LOCK" extension for instance), which you create just before reading or writing and delete just after. Then just test for its existence before reading or writing.

Comment: The easiest way to do what you're looking for is with a simple database like sqlite (http://www.sqlite.org/). Are you open to that possibility?

Comment: Yes, a sql approach would be best here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look at the sql approach